# How to derive this form

Tags: derivatives, hessian-matrix

can you please help me with the derivative of this function? I also need second derivative (need it for Hessian matrix) and I have no clue how to do it. Can you please help me?

$f(x)=\frac{1}{4}(x^TQx)^2 + \frac{1}{2}x^TAx + b^Tx$

Comment: The derivative of $x^TQX$ w.r.t. $x$ is $2Qx$. Otherwise apply the chain rule. Now it´s your turn!

Comment: Note that $\textbf Q$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

Derivative is done with chain rule

$$\nabla f(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x^TQx)(Q+Q^T)x+\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)x+b$$

I recomend you read [https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), it is a great book.